# Re[] and Im[] yielding Arg[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to obtain the real and imaginary parts of an eigenvalue from a matrix.

```
M00 = (q - r)/(2*dx)*deltaP - (q + r)/(2*dx)*deltaM;
M01 = -1/2*(1 + r*nu)* (q - r)/(2*dx)*deltaP -1/2*(1 - r*nu)*(q + r)/(2*dx)*deltaM;
M10 = 6*(1 + nu*r)*(q - r)/(2*dx)*deltaP +6*(1 - nu*r)*(q + r)/(2*dx)*deltaM;
M11 = (-3 - 6*nu*r - 2*(nu*r)^2)*(q - r)/(2*dx)*deltaP -6*r/dx*(q/r - nu*r) + (3 - 6*nu*r + 2*(nu*r)^2)*(q + r)/(2*dx)*deltaM;
M = ({{M00, M01},{M10, M11}});
G = IdentityMatrix[2] + dt*M;
Gs = Eigenvalues[G];
G1 = Gs[[2]] /. {deltaM -> (1 - Exp[-I*beta]),deltaP -> (Exp[I*beta] - 1)} // FullSimplify
G2 = Gs[[1]] /. {deltaM -> (1 - Exp[-I*beta]),deltaP -> (Exp[I*beta] - 1)} // FullSimplify;
G1Re = PowerExpand[ComplexExpand[Re[G1]]] // Simplify
G1Im = PowerExpand[ComplexExpand[Im[G1]]] // Simplify
```

The entire eigenvalue is given as
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\text{dt}^2 \text{dx}^4 \left(4\cos (\beta ) \left(\nu ^3 q r^4 (3-\nu q)+r^2 (\nu  q (2 \nu  q-9)+3)+2q^2\right)+2 i r \left(2 \sin (\beta )\left(\nu ^4 q r^4+\nu  r^2 (3-\nu  q (3 \nu q+2))+q (6 \nu  q-5)\right)+\sin (2 \beta )\left(\nu ^3 r^4 (3-\nu  q)+\nu  r^2 (\nu q-3) (3 \nu  q-1)+q (3 \nu q-1)\right)\right)+\cos (2 \beta ) \left(\nu^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 (\nu  q (\nu q-12)+10)+r^2 (2 \nu  q (5 \nu q-6)+1)+q^2\right)-\nu ^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4\left(3 \nu ^2 q^2+8\right)+r^2 (6 \nu  q(2-3 \nu  q)-13)+9 q^2\right)}}{\sqrt{2}\text{dx}^3}+\frac{\text{dt} \left(i r \sin(\beta ) \left(\nu ^2 r^2-3 \nu q+1\right)-\cos (\beta ) \left(\nu  r^2 (\nu q-3)+q\right)+q \left(\nu ^2r^2-2\right)\right)}{\text{dx}}+1,
$$

and the real and imaginary parts come out as

Re:
$$
\frac{\text{dt} \sqrt[4]{4 r^2 \left(2 \sin(\beta ) \left(\nu ^4 q r^4+\nu  r^2 (3-\nu q (3 \nu  q+2))+q (6 \nu  q-5)\right)+\sin(2 \beta ) \left(\nu ^3 r^4 (3-\nu  q)+\nu r^2 (\nu  q-3) (3 \nu  q-1)+q (3 \nu q-1)\right)\right)^2+\left(4 \cos (\beta )\left(\nu ^3 q r^4 (3-\nu  q)+r^2 (\nu  q (2\nu  q-9)+3)+2 q^2\right)+\cos (2 \beta )\left(\nu ^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 (\nu  q (\nu q-12)+10)+r^2 (2 \nu  q (5 \nu q-6)+1)+q^2\right)-\nu ^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4\left(3 \nu ^2 q^2+8\right)+r^2 (6 \nu  q(2-3 \nu  q)-13)+9 q^2\right)^2} \cos\left(\frac{1}{2} \arg \left(4 \cos (\beta )\left(\nu ^3 q r^4 (3-\nu  q)+r^2 (\nu  q (2\nu  q-9)+3)+2 q^2\right)+2 i r \left(2 \sin(\beta ) \left(\nu ^4 q r^4+\nu  r^2 (3-\nu q (3 \nu  q+2))+q (6 \nu  q-5)\right)+\sin(2 \beta ) \left(\nu ^3 r^4 (3-\nu  q)+\nu r^2 (\nu  q-3) (3 \nu  q-1)+q (3 \nu q-1)\right)\right)+\cos (2 \beta ) \left(\nu^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 (\nu  q (\nu q-12)+10)+r^2 (2 \nu  q (5 \nu q-6)+1)+q^2\right)-\nu ^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4\left(3 \nu ^2 q^2+8\right)+r^2 (6 \nu  q(2-3 \nu  q)-13)+9q^2\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2}\text{dx}}-\frac{\text{dt} \nu ^2 q r^2 \cos(\beta )}{\text{dx}}+\frac{3 \text{dt} \nu r^2 \cos (\beta)}{\text{dx}}-\frac{\text{dt} q \cos (\beta)}{\text{dx}}+\frac{\text{dt} \nu ^2 qr^2}{\text{dx}}-\frac{2 \text{dt}q}{\text{dx}}+1,
$$

Im:

$$
\frac{\text{dt} \left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{4 r^2\left(2 \sin (\beta ) \left(\nu ^4 q r^4+\nu r^2 (3-\nu  q (3 \nu  q+2))+q (6 \nu q-5)\right)+\sin (2 \beta ) \left(\nu ^3 r^4(3-\nu  q)+\nu  r^2 (\nu  q-3) (3 \nu q-1)+q (3 \nu  q-1)\right)\right)^2+\left(4\cos (\beta ) \left(\nu ^3 q r^4 (3-\nu q)+r^2 (\nu  q (2 \nu  q-9)+3)+2q^2\right)+\cos (2 \beta ) \left(\nu ^4r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 (\nu  q (\nu  q-12)+10)+r^2(2 \nu  q (5 \nu  q-6)+1)+q^2\right)-\nu ^4r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 \left(3 \nu ^2q^2+8\right)+r^2 (6 \nu  q (2-3 \nu q)-13)+9 q^2\right)^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \arg \left(4 \cos (\beta )\left(\nu ^3 q r^4 (3-\nu  q)+r^2 (\nu  q (2\nu  q-9)+3)+2 q^2\right)+2 i r \left(2 \sin(\beta ) \left(\nu ^4 q r^4+\nu  r^2 (3-\nu q (3 \nu  q+2))+q (6 \nu  q-5)\right)+\sin(2 \beta ) \left(\nu ^3 r^4 (3-\nu  q)+\nu r^2 (\nu  q-3) (3 \nu  q-1)+q (3 \nu q-1)\right)\right)+\cos (2 \beta ) \left(\nu^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4 (\nu  q (\nu q-12)+10)+r^2 (2 \nu  q (5 \nu q-6)+1)+q^2\right)-\nu ^4 r^6+\nu ^2 r^4\left(3 \nu ^2 q^2+8\right)+r^2 (6 \nu  q(2-3 \nu  q)-13)+9 q^2\right)\right)+2 \nu^2 r^3 \sin (\beta )-6 \nu  q r \sin (\beta)+2 r \sin (\beta )\right)}{2 \text{dx}}
$$

The resulting expressions are hard to look at, but there is an Arg[] command in both expressions, as well as imaginary numbers that remain in the real part. Why isn't the statement being fully evaluated and simply giving me the real and imaginary parts?

I have used ComplexExpand as I see recommended elsewhere, but it hasn't helped. What assumptions do I need to give mathematica to let it expand all this?

Comment: Per the docs `Re` remains unevaluated for non-numeric quantities.  I don't think you are going to get the output you desire with this function.

Comment: But with assumptions/ComplexExpand mathematica should be able to give me the real and imaginary parts of an expression. I just don't see why it's yielding an Arg[]  function within the expression, or what assumptions I have to provide it with to allow it to evaluate Re/Im.

Comment: I think you should look at the Option [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html).  In particular `TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}`

Comment: In addition to tips you have already got,  I recommend remembering that by default, Mma regards all variables as complex ones. This may prevent a simplification on some step. Therefore, if some (or all) of them are reals or positive, it is worth specifying it during simplification. From the first glance, however, you have too many variables suggesting that the expression hardly can become much more simple.

Comment: `Arg` is real-valued, regardless of what is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on tips in the comments, the following works for me (do the same for the Im[] part):

```
G1Re = PowerExpand[ComplexExpand[Re[G1], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]] // Simplify
```

= (1/(2 dx))(2 dx - 4 dt q + 2 dt nu^2 q r^2 -
2 dt q Cos[beta] + 6 dt nu r^2 Cos[beta] -
2 dt nu^2 q r^2 Cos[beta] +
Sqrt[2] dt Cos[
1/2 ArcTan[
9 q^2 + (-13 + 6 nu q (2 - 3 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^2 (8 + 3 nu^2 q^2) r^4 - nu^4 r^6 +
4 (2 q^2 + (3 + nu q (-9 + 2 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^3 q (3 - nu q) r^4) Cos[
beta] + (q^2 + (1 + 2 nu q (-6 + 5 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^2 (10 + nu q (-12 + nu q)) r^4 + nu^4 r^6) Cos[2 beta],
2 r (2 (q (-5 + 6 nu q) + nu (3 - nu q (2 + 3 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^4 q r^4) Sin[
beta] + (q (-1 + 3 nu q) +
nu (-3 + nu q) (-1 + 3 nu q) r^2 +
nu^3 (3 - nu q) r^4) Sin[2 beta])]] ((9 q^2 + (-13 +
6 nu q (2 - 3 nu q)) r^2 + nu^2 (8 + 3 nu^2 q^2) r^4 -
nu^4 r^6 +
4 (2 q^2 + (3 + nu q (-9 + 2 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^3 q (3 - nu q) r^4) Cos[
beta] + (q^2 + (1 + 2 nu q (-6 + 5 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^2 (10 + nu q (-12 + nu q)) r^4 + nu^4 r^6) Cos[
2 beta])^2 +
4 r^2 (2 (q (-5 + 6 nu q) + nu (3 - nu q (2 + 3 nu q)) r^2 +
nu^4 q r^4) Sin[
beta] + (q (-1 + 3 nu q) +
nu (-3 + nu q) (-1 + 3 nu q) r^2 +
nu^3 (3 - nu q) r^4) Sin[2 beta])^2)^(1/4))

The documentation for ComplexExpand[ ] indicates that it assumes all variables are real.